# jquery datepicker not working on created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have very simple datepicker setup:

this in `<head>`

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection,tv" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('input.date').datepicker();

        $('button').on('click', function() {
            $('#orig').clone()
                .attr('id', 'else')
                .datepicker()
                .appendTo('body');
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this in `<body>`

```
<input type="date" id="orig" class="date">
<button>duplicate</button>
```

When input is cloned datepicker is not initialized on it. See on http://jsfiddle.net/aMPB2/

What is wrong with it?

Comment: I was **sure** that reversing the `datepicker` and `appendTo` calls would fix it. It didn't. :-)

Comment: I tried that too, @T.J.Crowder

Comment: I tried that too :) and many other combinations but the removal of class didn't come to my mind at all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`datepicker` adds a marker class "hasDatepicker" to the element. You have to remove it from the clone:

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aMPB2/3/)

```
$(function() {
    $('input.date').datepicker();

    $('button').on('click', function() {
        var x = $('#orig').clone()
        .attr('id', 'else')
        .removeClass("hasDatepicker")    // <=== New line
        .appendTo('body')
        .datepicker();
    });
});
```

Comment: How I got there: My first assumption was something set via the `data` function, but there wasn't anything. So then I right-clicked the source element in Chrome and choose "Inspect element", and there was the class...

Comment: Oh, I should have asked sooner so I woudln't have to waste an hour on that! Thank you!